# Deleting DT::datatable's header results in 'no matching records found' when using renderDT() in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Trying to delete the headers from DT::datatable results in `'No matching records found'` when used inside  `renderDT()`. Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
    dashboardSidebar(
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        DT::dataTableOutput("t")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$t<-renderDT(datatable(head(iris),colnames = ""))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution for this problem is to set the `server` argument in `renderDT()` to `FALSE`. However, the description of this argument says:

> if FALSE, then the entire data frame is sent to the browser at once. Highly recommended for medium to large data frames, which can cause browsers to slow down or crash.

If this is not of a problem for you, try this:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
  dashboardSidebar(
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    DT::dataTableOutput("t")
  )
)
debugonce(renderDT)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$t <- renderDT(datatable(head(iris),colnames = ""), server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `colnames` parameter, or give a character vector of column names

---

##### TL;DR

I had the same problem from inside a module call. It took me a while to figure it out.

The root cause is the `colnames` parameter inside `datatable` (or equivalently as a `...` parameter inside `renderDT`). Only use it to rename column names for the UI header.

---

As an example with your code but with a useful parameter:

```
library(shiny)
library(semantic.dashboard)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
    dashboardSidebar(
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        DT::dataTableOutput("t")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$t <- renderDT(
        datatable(
            head(iris),
            colnames = c(
                "Sepal length (mm)",
                "Sepal width (mm)",
                "Petal length (mm)",
                "Petal width (mm)",
                "Specie name"
            )
        )
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

No need to set `server = FALSE` for this case IMHO.